# Overwriting the default case class constructor (Scala)

Tags: scala, case-class

If I have a case class:

```
case class NonNegativeInt(i: Int)
```

where the field `i` to be set to 0 if the parameter is negative. So I cannot just use the default constructor provided by the case class. If I define an apply() method in the companion object (or wherever):

```
def apply(n: Int) = new NonNegativeInt(Math.max(0, n))
```

Apparently they have the same signature. Is there a practical way/pattern to process the constraints on the fields?

Comment: I don't understand why you would not want `NonNegativeInt(-100)` to return `NonNegativeInt(0)`. Your case class name itself is very clear that it is non-negative so `apply()` seems good to me. Are you saying you want to call something as `SomeClass.someMethodThatReturnsNonNegative(int: Int): NonoNegativeInt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I mostly agree with @flavian's answer that you should use another name for your method, what you can do is not make a case class at all. Or rather, implement by hand all that the case class construct gives you:

```
class NonNegativeInt private (val i: Int) {
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that.isInstanceOf[NonNegativeInt] && that.asInstanceOf[NonNegativeInt].i == i
  override def hashCode = i.hashCode

  def copy(i: Int = this.i) = NonNegativeInt(i)  //use companion apply method, not private constructor
}

object NonNegativeInt {
  def apply(i: Int) = 
    new NonNegativeInt(if (i < 0) 0 else i)

  def unapply(that: NonNegativeInt): Option[Int] = Some(that.i)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
case class NonNegativeInt(i: Int)
```

If you can't use apply just name it something else.

```
object NonNegativeInt {
  def fromInt(i: Int): NonNegativeInt = NonNegativeInt(Math.max(0, i)
}
```

You can get fancier if you like, typecheck literal constants with compile time restrictions on positive ints with `Refined` or `shapeless`, hide the primary constructor by sealing the `case class` or other such means, but it feels a bit overkill under the circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

There is no straight forward way to override case class constructor as far as I know. However, assuming that real data type won't be simple int, you could do some type which considers invalid state like below:

```
sealed abstract class NonNegativeInt { def isValid: Boolean }
final case class ValidNonNegativeInt(i: Int) extends NonNegativeInt { override def isValid: Boolean = true }
final case object InvalidNonNegativeInt extends NonNegativeInt { override def isValid: Boolean = false }
object NonNegativeInt {
  def apply(i: Int): NonNegativeInt = if (i < 0) InvalidNonNegativeInt else ValidNonNegativeInt(i)
}
```

This works pretty simple:

```
scala>   NonNegativeInt(0)
res5: NonNegativeInt = ValidNonNegativeInt(0)

scala>   NonNegativeInt(-1)
res6: NonNegativeInt = InvalidNonNegativeInt
```

Then you can even do pattern matching:

```
val ni = NonNegativeInt(10)
ni match {
    case ValidNonNegativeInt(i) => println(s"valid $i")
    case InvalidNonNegativeInt => println(s"invalid")
}
```

Then you could further extend your functionality with map/flatMap etc.

Of course it still not protecting you from negative case:

```
scala>   ValidNonNegativeInt(-10)
res7: ValidNonNegativeInt = ValidNonNegativeInt(-10)
```

But scala Option for instance also does not override constructor for Some() case allowing invalid value:

```
scala> Option(null)
res8: Option[Null] = None

scala> Some(null)
res9: Some[Null] = Some(null)
```

Unless there is no critical use case, for simple Int I would leave it as it is, and ensure its correctness in usages. For more complex structures, above way is quite useful.

> Note: I intentionally not used your Max(0, n) way, as in this case it
>   will cause more problems than it would solve. Assuming something, and
>   swapping data under the hood is bad practice. Imagine you will have a
>   bug somewhere in other place of your code which will use your
>   implementation with Max(0, n). If input data would be -10, most likely,
>   problem was caused by some other problem in incoming data. When you
>   change it to default 0, even through input was -10, later when you
>   will analyze logs, dumps or debug output, you will miss the fact that it
>   was -10.

---

Other solutions, in my point of view:

@flavian solution is most logical. Explicit functionality/validation

@Cyrille Corpet: very Java'ish

@jwvh solution will take double amount of memory footprint, since it will be two `Int`s in memory. And also will not protect from overriding:

```
scala>   case class NonNegativeInt1(private val x:Int)(implicit val i:Int = Math.max(0,x)) {
     |     override def toString: String = s"NonNegativeInt1($x, $i)"
     |   }
defined class NonNegativeInt1

scala>   NonNegativeInt1(5)
res10: NonNegativeInt1 = NonNegativeInt1(5, 5)

scala>   NonNegativeInt1(-5)
res11: NonNegativeInt1 = NonNegativeInt1(-5, 0)

scala>   NonNegativeInt1(-5)(-5)
res12: NonNegativeInt1 = NonNegativeInt1(-5, -5)
```